# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str', but actually a similar code can run.Why this happens?

Tags: python, list

```
#function vathmon
def grade_list(grade):
    test_num = int(input('How many test scores do you want to enter: '))
    for g in range(test_num):
        print('Enter grade for student #', g+1,sep='')
        grade.append(input('Enter score: '))
    return grade    
#functiopn mesou orou
def average_grade(grade, ):
    grade = int(sum(grade))/(len(grade))
    return grade

def show_results(grade, over):
    for i in range(grade):
        if grade > over :
                  print(grade)              
    

def main():
    grades = []
    grade_list(grades)
    final_result = average_grade(grades)
    show_results(final_result)

main()
```

Comment: `input` returns the value as a `str`. You're probably looking for `int(input('Enter score: '))`, assuming the proper value is inputted

Comment: Where exactly does the error happen (please show the complete error message including traceback), and which is the similar code that runs without error?

Answer (score 2):

Your `grade_list` function returns a list of strings, but `average_grade` expects a list of numbers (it calls `sum(grade)`, which trades the contents of the list as numbers).

Here's a fixed version of the code with type annotations that show what type of parameters each function is expected to take.  Note that `grade_list` has been modified to return a `List[int]`, by making sure that each item appended to `grades` is an `int`.  We can then just pass the resulting list to `statistics.mean` rather than having to implement our own averaging function.

```
from statistics import mean
from typing import List


def grade_list() -> List[int]:
    test_num = int(input('How many test scores do you want to enter: '))
    grades: List[int] = []
    for g in range(1, test_num + 1):
        print(f'Enter grade for student #{g}')
        grades.append(int(input('Enter score: ')))
    return grades


def show_results(grades: List[int], over: float) -> None:
    for grade in grades:
        if grade > over:
            print(grade)


def main() -> None:
    grades = grade_list()
    average = mean(grades)
    show_results(grades, average)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
How many test scores do you want to enter: 3
Enter grade for student #1
Enter score: 100
Enter grade for student #2
Enter score: 90
Enter grade for student #3
Enter score: 50
100
90
```

Answer (score 1):

try:
`print('Enter grade for student #', int(g)+1,sep='')`